# Как обойти двоичную погрешность JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

Есть такая задача: 
  Имеется **n кг** металлического сплава. Из него изготавливают заготовки массой **k кг** каждая.
  
 После этого из каждой заготовки вытачиваются детали массой **m кг** каждая (из каждой заготовки вытачивают максимально возможное количество деталей).
  
 Если от заготовок после этого что-то остается, то этот материал возвращают к началу производственного цикла и сплавляют с тем, что осталось при изготовлении заготовок. Если того сплава, который получился, достаточно для изготовления хотя бы
  одной заготовки, то из него снова изготавливают заготовки, из них — детали и т.д.
  
 Напишите программу, которая вычислит, какое количество деталей может быть получено по этой технологии из исходного **n кг** сплава

```js
function calcMetall(n, k, m, sum = 0) {
  console.log(n, 'кг металлического сплава');
  console.log(k, 'кг масса одной заготовки');
  console.log(m, 'кг масса одной детали');

  console.log('');
  const kPieces = Math.trunc(n / k);
  const kBalance = n - kPieces * k;
  console.log(kPieces, 'заготовок');
  console.log(kBalance, 'Остаток сплава от заготовок');
  console.log('');
  // Я предполагаю, что заготовку стругают и из неё всегда получается деталь, оставшийся мусор пускают на следующий цикл переработки
  const mPieces = kPieces;
  const mBalance = k * kPieces - m * mPieces;
  console.log(mPieces, 'деталей');
  console.log(mBalance, 'Остаток сплава от деталей');
  const balance = kBalance + mBalance;
  console.log(balance, 'Общий остаток');
  sum = sum + mPieces;
  console.log('----------------------------------');
  if (balance > k) {
    return calcMetall(balance, k, m, sum);
  }
  return sum;
}

const sum = calcMetall(2, 0.3, 0.2);
console.log(sum);
```

```
console.log(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3); // false
console.log(0.3); // 0.30000000000000004
console.log(2 - 6*0.3); // 0.20000000000000018
```

Я не понимаю, как мне обойти эту погрешность, чтобы моя программа работала правильно при разных входных данных

**UPD:**
Не понимаю, почему здесь опять появляется неточность

```js
function toTochno(n) {
  if (n > 1 / Math.pow(10, 15)) {
    return Math.round(n * Math.pow(10, 15)) / Math.pow(10, 15);
  } else {
    return n;
  }
}

function calcMetall(n, k, m, sum = 0) {
  console.log(n, 'кг металлического сплава');
  console.log(k, 'кг масса одной заготовки');
  console.log(m, 'кг масса одной детали');

  console.log('');
  const kPieces = Math.trunc(n / k);
  const kBalance = toTochno(n - kPieces * k);
  console.log(kPieces, 'заготовок');
  console.log(kBalance, 'Остаток сплава от заготовок');
  console.log('');
  const mPieces = toTochno(Math.trunc(k / m) * kPieces);
  const mBalance = toTochno(k * kPieces - m * mPieces);
  console.log(mPieces, 'деталей');
  console.log(mBalance, 'Остаток сплава от деталей');
  const balance = toTochno(kBalance + mBalance);
  console.log(balance, 'Общий остаток');
  sum = sum + mPieces;
  console.log('----------------------------------');
  if (balance > k) {
    return calcMetall(balance, k, m, sum);
  }
  return sum;
}

const sum = calcMetall(100, 0.3, 0.2);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Отделите вычисления от манипуляций с DOM-элементами.

Comment: @Igor сделано, .

Comment: О какой "этой" погрешности речь?

Comment: @Эникейщик https://learn.javascript.ru/number#netochnye-vychisleniya

Comment: Почему просто не округлить? Скажем `Math.round(sum*10)/10`

Comment: Не надо давать ссылки на непонятные ресурсы, вопрос должен быть самодосаточным В вопросе написано "эта погрешность", хотя никакая погрешность там не упоминается.

Comment: В чем проблема то, неточность возникает только в пределах одной 1е-17, кому нужна такая точность? Если применять Math.round(sum*1e16)/1e16 для результата каждого математического вычисления, то и вопросов нет. Все будет точно.

Comment: `из каждой заготовки вытачивают максимально возможное количество деталей` подразумевает, что из заготовки может получиться несколько деталей

Comment: @MBo вроде это поправил, но теперь опять столкнулся с погрешностью

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Как почему, потому что отрубали после 15 знака после запятой, глядя на прежние вычисления, опытным путем, а оказалось, что бывают и после 12 знака погрешности)) опять же опытным путем... В общем, я подход предложил.

Comment: @Leonid я попробую сделать функцию-замыкание, которая будет определять, в какую степень надо возводить

Comment: Мне удалить ответ?

Comment: Неточность есть неточность. Для всех примеров здесь достаточно и `Math.round(sum*10)/10` как я предложил вначале. Если потеря десятой нанограмма не устраивает, то можно перевести в граммы и так далее. Всё равно это костыли и допущения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По большому счету кг можно выразить в граммах, микрограммах, нанограммах. Тогда удастся избежать неточностей. Если максимальное число в JS ~9e15, то в нанограммах можно выразить до 9 тонн без всяких нецелых чисел.

**Если позволяет точность до нанограмма:**

```js
function toTochno(n) {
return Math.round(n * Math.pow(10, 12)) / Math.pow(10, 12);
}

function calcMetall(n, k, m, sum = 0) {
  console.log(n, 'кг металлического сплава');
  console.log(k, 'кг масса одной заготовки');
  console.log(m, 'кг масса одной детали');

  console.log('');
  const kPieces = Math.trunc(n / k);
  
  const kBalance = toTochno(n - kPieces * k);
  
  console.log(kPieces, 'заготовок');
  console.log(kBalance, 'Остаток сплава от заготовок');
  
  
  console.log('');
  const mPieces = toTochno(Math.trunc(k / m) * kPieces);
  const mBalance = toTochno(k * kPieces - m * mPieces);
  console.log(mPieces, 'деталей');
  console.log(mBalance, 'Остаток сплава от деталей');
  const balance = toTochno(kBalance + mBalance);
  console.log(balance, 'Общий остаток');
  sum = sum + mPieces;
  console.log('----------------------------------');
  if (balance > k) {
return calcMetall(balance, k, m, sum);
  }
  return sum;
}

const sum = calcMetall(100, 0.3, 0.2);
console.log(sum);
```

**Еще проще если использовать граммы!!!:**

```js
function calcMetall(n, k, m, sum = 0) {
  console.log(n, 'г металлического сплава');
  console.log(k, 'г масса одной заготовки');
  console.log(m, 'г масса одной детали');

  console.log('');
  const kPieces = Math.trunc(n / k);
  
  const kBalance = n - kPieces * k;
  
  console.log(kPieces, 'заготовок');
  console.log(kBalance, 'Остаток сплава от заготовок');
  
  
  console.log('');
  const mPieces = Math.trunc(k / m) * kPieces;
  const mBalance = k * kPieces - m * mPieces;
  console.log(mPieces, 'деталей');
  console.log(mBalance, 'Остаток сплава от деталей');
  const balance = kBalance + mBalance;
  console.log(balance, 'Общий остаток');
  sum = sum + mPieces;
  console.log('----------------------------------');
  if (balance > k) {
return calcMetall(balance, k, m, sum);
  }
  return sum;
}

const sum = calcMetall(100000, 300, 200);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: я понимаю, что можно сделать так, чтобы посчитать `0.1 + 0.2`, `(0.1*10 + 0.2*10)/10`, но надо же ещё все операции смотреть как выполняются и на нужное количество нулей умножать

Comment: Есть предел необходимой точности, если погрешность возникает выше это предела, то да, - не пойдет так, а если нужны данные вроде 0.002 и 0.003, то способ подходит на все сто. Разве нет?

Comment: обновил вопрос, не понимаю, почему есть неточность